# Is checking the size of a list linear?

Tags: arrays, list, linked-list, time-complexity, string-length

I've seen many answers online saying that checking the size of a list is constant time, but I don't understand why.

My understanding was that a list isn't stored in contiguous memory chunks (like an array), meaning there is no way of getting the size of a list (last element index + 1), without first traversing through every element.

Thoughts?

Comment: Can you reference some of these answers you see? Obviously, you're right, but taken out of context maybe they're referring to keeping the size as a piece of data in a structure, in which case it is constant time.

Comment: If this question is about Python, please [edit] your question to remove [linked-list] and add [python]. I would probably remove [linked-list] anyway since you reference arrays/list, and nothing about linked lists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I've seen many answers online saying that checking the size of a list is constant time.

This fallacy may originate in a fundamental flaw in the Python language: arrays are called *lists* in Python. As Python gains popularity, the word *list* has become ambiguous.

Computing the length of a linked list is an **O(n)** operation, unless the length has been stored separately and maintained properly.

Retrieving the size of an array is performed in constant time if the size is stored along with the array, as is the case in Python, so `a=[1,2,3]; len(a)` is indeed very fast.

Computing the length of an array may be an **O(n)** operation if the array must be scanned for a terminating value, such as a null pointer or a null byte. Thus `strlen()` in C, which computes the number of bytes in a C string (a null terminated array of `char`) operates in linear time.

Answer (score 1):

The only way to find the length of a list without holding the locations before hand is iterating through the list. They are not stored in chunks so it requires iterating until reaching the last element. Therefore the time complexity is O(n). Of course if you store a variable holding the length and increment it every time an element is added (and decrement when an element is removed), you would not need to iterate through it which would make it constant as you would only need the first element, or retrieve the data from wherever the length is stored. Perhaps one could use the root element to hold the length therefore making it unnecessary to loop through it to get the length. In short, you are correct. The reason one might say constant is if it is stored beforehand.